# Postfix relay denied

Tags: postfix, smtp, relay

I have installed Cyberpanel with postfix installed
I am facing Relay Denied error while sending out the emails i.e.gmail.com or any other external

I have tried googling and read many posts but not able to get is work

The main.cf is as under

```
myhostname = vmi1029709.contaboserver.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
#ynetworks = 0.0.0.0/0, 127.0.0.0/8
message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

the error log shows

```
Oct  7 12:33:31 vmi1029709 postfix/smtpd[259061]: connect from unknown[182.191.133.112]
Oct  7 12:33:32 vmi1029709 postfix/smtpd[259061]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[182.191.133.112]: 554 5.7.1 <rizwan65@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<rizwan@progressngo.org> to=<rizwan65@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<RizwanPC>
Oct  7 12:33:35 vmi1029709 postfix/smtpd[259061]: disconnect from unknown[182.191.133.112] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=3/4
```

Any suggestions
Rizwan

---

Well
I am using outlook as mail client and using smtp authentication while sending mails

If I send mail to the another domain hosted on this server. It goes fine
But if I send mail to external domain i.e. gmail.com etc. its relay is denied.
whereas I connect with same IP both times

Answer (score 1):

The connection is coming from outside `mynetworks` and doesn't appear to be authenticated, and gmail.com should not be a permitted destination for relaying.

In short, everything *is* configured correctly. You do **not** want to be an open relay.

Deliveries originating from `localhost` should work given your configuration. External connections should be authenticated using SASL to allow relaying. Based on the log entry you show, your client doesn't attempt authentication.